# How to configure django with xampp mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, xampp

I'm new at Django. After configuring the settings when I tried to migrate with mysql then it said "Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?" I have already xampp installed on my machine so I don't want to install mysql server again and mysql is running well on xampp. Then I've installed "python-mysqldb" for mysql binding. But the same error again. After that I've installed mysqlclient as the error then ran the migrate again but now its saying I don't have a mysql server. But the mysql is running on xampp. What should I do? Should I install mysql server? There is no way to use xampp? I didn't find any useful article on google about that.

Here is my database configuration,

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'todolist',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306'
}
```

}

[error that asking for mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYywC.png)
And
[error that saying there is no mysql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vud9.png)

Comment: Did you run what the error suggest to, install mysqlclient? Use `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Comment: Yeah I did that, then it says I don't have a mysql server...a screenshot of that problem I've already provided with the post. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw on your screenshots, you're using Ubuntu. I think that the best way to use MySQL with Django Application is to install standalone MySQL server.
What you need to do is:

1. Install MySQL

   sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
2. Install mysqlclient package

   pip install django mysqlclient

Credit: [How To Use MySQL or MariaDB with your Django Application on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)